# How can i change the variable name in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have some js code like this:

```
var parameter0 = 12345;
var parameter1 = 54321;
var parameter2 = 33333;
var parameter3 = 99990;

function selectValue(number) {
alert(parameter+number);
}

selectValue(2);
```

Here is a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/frwd2qLg/

This code will not work, because, for example, for number = 2, it will not show 33333, but will be undefined. Any workaround?

Comment: This sound like an [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you trying to do that? Consider using an array, with the index as the number input.

Comment: Learn about the use of arrays: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: You are reinventing arrays or objects or maps.

Comment: `eval` is dangerous, but might be what you are looking for here (but it would be better to follow the other advice here)

Comment: `var parameters = [12345, 54321, 33333, 99990]; console.log(parameters[number]);`

Comment: yes, i just converted this into one array and use parameters[i], thanks

Answer (score 0):

As people said in your comments, you could use an array or an object to do this task. But answering your question you culd use an `eval` to access the variable name.

```js
var parameter0 = 12345;
var parameter1 = 54321;
var parameter2 = 33333;
var parameter3 = 99990;

function selectValue(number) {
  alert(eval("parameter"+number));
}

selectValue(2);
```